# How do I find the right Friends?

Tags: javascript

I am not sure how to find the right one or to search me out of it

// Assignment 8: Fix the code

```js
// Assignment 8: Fix the code
var Friends = (function() {
  var i = 0; 
  function Friends() {
    var ival = setInterval(function() {
      console.log(this.friends[i]);
      i++;
      if(i === this.friends.length) {
        clearInterval(ival);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
  Friends.prototype.friends = ['Mikkel', 'Jens', 'Filip'];
  return Friends;
})();

var f = new Friends();
var f2 = new Friends();

/* it should log:
Mikkel
Mikkel
Jens
Jens
Filip
Fili
```

/* it should log:
Mikkel
Mikkel
Jens
Jens
Filip
Fili

Comment: I'm asking myself the same question :'(

Comment: Please have a look at the [help] on how to ask. You haven't asked an actual question here, you haven't explained what the problem is, what it actually logs if it doesn't do what it should etc. Also if it's an assignment from school or similar, please note it properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with this code snippet,

1. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`
2. `context of variable "i" is same for both instance of friends.`

First issue was due to the context of the variable `this` inside `setInterval` function. To access the `friends` inside `setInterval` keep the reference of this into a variable outside `setInterval` and access that variable inside the function. In the below code I have assigned `this` to a variable `me`, and accessed `friends` list using `me`.

Second issue is with the indexing of item using `i`. As we have defined it out side the function `Friends`, indexing will same in both initialisation. Which will result in following result:

```
Mikkel
Jens
Filip
undefined
undefined
undefined ....
```

So to make sure when ever we call `new Friends()` the it should start from the beginning of the friends list move the initialisation of `var i = 0` inside Friends function.

## Below is the updated code which will give the exact result.

```js
var Friends = (function() {
  function Friends() {
    var i = 0; // Solution for second issue
    var me = this; // Solution for first issue
    var ival = setInterval(function() {
      console.log(me.friends[i]);
      i++;
      if(i === me.friends.length) {
        clearInterval(ival);
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
  Friends.prototype.friends = ['Mikkel', 'Jens', 'Filip'];
  return Friends;
})();



var f = new Friends();
var f2 = new Friends();
```